# Custom FBA login page SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication

I am trying to develop a custom FBA login page in SharePoint 2013

I am following this article 
[Custom FBA][1]  [1]: http://msreddysharepoint.blogspot.com/2013/03/custom-fba-login-page-or-sigin-page.html

I have created a brand new web application  and root site collection 
I have claims authentication and I have checked the default login page to begin my custom
log in development

I am using visual studio  2013

1. create a empty SharePoint project (SharePointProject1)
2. Add a layout folder in the newly created project
3. add new item -- Application page (applicationpage1.aspx)
4. I add the code in the article and then deploy it
5. I go to the web application and change the default login page to custom login page:

   `~/layouts/SharePointProject1/Applicationpage1.aspx`
6. I type in the http request
7. I get the following error:

> XML Parsing Error: syntax error
>
> Layouts/SharePointProject1.Layouts.SharePointProject1/ApplicationPage1.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2F
>
> Line Number 1, Column 1:404 NOT FOUND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url  you should use is `/_layouts/15/SharePointProject1/Applicationpage1.aspx`